# Triggering jquery function some time after document is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck trying to trigger a function after, say, 2 seconds after document is loaded.

The function is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.trigger').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.popcircle('#pops', {
            spacing:'15px',
            type:'full', // full, half, quad
            offset:1.95, // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 or 5.1
            ease:'easeOutElastic',
            time:'slow' // slow, fast, 1000
        });
    });
});
```

and I tried several ways similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.popcircle('#pops', {
            spacing:'15px',
            type:'full', // full, half, quad
            offset:1.95, // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 or 5.1
            ease:'easeOutElastic',
            time:'slow' // slow, fast, 1000
        }    
    }, 2000);
});
```

But it simply does not work. I've read and tried some possible solutions but neither they do work to me. (?)

Any clue? Need more info?

Comment: _“But it simply does not work”_ – and you simply did not bother to check your browser’s JS console for errors. Otherwise it should have told you immediately that there is no `e` object that a method `preventDefault` could be called upon. You are not even dealing with an event here any more in your delayed function, so keeping this line makes no sense at all.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how to do it. Didn't want to annoy anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistakes in your code:

1. As @CBroe mentioned, there is no `e`. As a result

   > Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

   You should remove the following line because there's no event you're dealing with:

   ```
   e.preventDefault();
   ```
2. A syntax error in `$.popcircle` function:

   > Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

   Just add a `);`

As a result, your code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.popcircle('#pops', {
            spacing:'15px',
            type:'full', // full, half, quad
            offset:1.95,    // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 or 5.1
            ease:'easeOutElastic',
            time:'slow' // slow, fast, 1000
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Ty, Alex. Still doesn't work. It doesn't trigger the function that was triggered by 'click'. Anyway, as CBroe suggested above I should learn first the proper tools.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it does work. There may be some kind of issue in the associated jquery plugin because it does work when I trigger the function twice it does what it was supposed to do. Now I remember I also had to do double-click twice before starting the (visibly effects of the) function.

Thanks a lot. Have a nice day!